# Can't set the data to a comboBox choice

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

it has been days I'm trying to create a comboBox with all available models.
The code is this

```
for name , models in SortedPairs( player_manager.AllValidModels() ) do
   print("name: "..name.." model: "..models)
   custCbox:AddChoice(name , models , false)
end
```

I tried to print every name and model to know if I was wrong, but that's ok: name prints the display name and models prints the path.
The OnSelect function is this:

```
custCbox.OnSelect = function( index, value, data )
   modelPanel:SetModel( data )
   print("Data " .. data)
   print("Value " .. value)
end
```

Data gives the display name and value gives a number.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [DComboBox documentation](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/DComboBox:OnSelect):

```
local cbox = vgui.Create( "DComboBox", BGPanel )
```

...

```
cbox:AddChoice( "Pink", Color( 255, 0, 255 ) )

function cbox:OnSelect( index, text, data )

    -- Set background panel color
    BGPanel:SetBackgroundColor( data )

end
```

Note the difference to your

```
custCbox.OnSelect = function( index, value, data )
   modelPanel:SetModel( data )
   print("Data " .. data)
   print("Value " .. value)
end
```

which is equivalent to

```
function custCbox.onSelect(index, value, data)
-- ...
end
```

And the example that uses the colon syntax.

```
function cbox:OnSelect(index, text, data)
end
```

is equivalent to

```
function cbox.OnSelect(self, index, text, data)
end
```

This difference causes a parameter shift by one. So what you think is `index` is actually your combobox, `text` is the selected index and `data` is the choices text.

Please read

[Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 3.4.10 Function Calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.10)

[Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 3.4.11 Function Definitions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.11)

This is a very common mistake among beginners.